# python - 24hr format for datetime.now().hour

Tags: python, datetime

I would like to start and end my program at a certain time of each day. E.g. starts at 10p.m. and ends at 6a.m.

Using the method of `dt.now().hour in range(10,6)`does not seem to work. I tried to change it to `dt.now().hour in range(22,6)`the result is the same. However for `dt.now().hour in range(2,6)` it works fine.

**python code**

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from time import time, sleep

while True:
    if dt.now().hour in range(10,3):
        print('time to sleep')
        sleep(10)

    else:
        print('time to work')
        sleep(10)
```

Comment: The better thing to do would be to run the program as a cronjob and run it for the period needed: https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/schedule-jobs-with-crontab-on-mac-osx.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do two checks

```
if dt.now().hour in range(22,24) or dt.now().hour in range(0, 6):
    print("working")
else:
    print("sleeping")
```

Answer (score 0):

`range(10,3)` returns an empty range, since 10 > 3. You need to check if hour is in range 22-24 **or** in range 0-6. Another solution is to check if hour is **not** in range 6-22.